# How to select deeper elements created dynamically?

Tags: jquery

I created elements inside an `ajax` script :

```
<?php
...
foreach ($rows as $row) {

   $no_rows = false;

   $img = ($row["img_fichier"] === NULL ? HTTP_IMG.'default_article.jpg' : HTTP_IMG.$row["img_fichier"]);

   $msg .= '<div id="tile_article_'.$row["article_id"].'" data-pk="'.$row["article_id"].'" class="tile fg-black" style="text-align:center;">
                <div class="tile-content">
                    <label class="input-control checkbox small-check">
                        <input class="article" id="article_'.$row["article_id"].'" name="article_'.$row["article_id"].'" type="checkbox" value="'.$row["article_id"].'" />
                        <span class="check"></span>
                        <span class="caption">'.$row["article_lib"].'</span>
                    </label>
                    <input type="text" id="qtecmd_'.$row["article_id"].'" name="qtecmd_'.$row["article_id"].'" placeholder="'._getText('souscommande.qte.placeholder').'" class="numeric qtecmd" />
                    <div class="image-container">
                        <div class="frame"><img src="'.$img.'" /></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>';
}
...
echo $msg;
}
?>
```

The `responseText` of this `ajax` will be inserted into this `div` :

```
<div id="cmds"></div>
```

In the `$(document).ready` I call the `ajax` because there are `$_GET` parameters gotten from another page :

```
<script>
function loadData(page) {

        var cols = "article_id,article_lib,img_fichier";

        var tabs = "article a LEFT JOIN image i ON a.img_id = i.img_id";

        var where = "";
        if ($("#famille_article").val() != "") {
            if (where == "")
                where += "WHERE a.fam_arti_code = '"+$("#famille_article").val()+"'";
            else
                where += " AND a.fam_arti_code = '"+$("#famille_article").val()+"'";
        }
        if ($("#categorie_article").val() != "") {
            if (where == "")
                where += "WHERE a.cat_arti_code = '"+$("#categorie_article").val()+"'";
            else
                where += " AND a.cat_arti_code = '"+$("#categorie_article").val()+"'";
        }

        var ret = $.ajax ({
                            type: "POST",
                            async: false,
                            data: "nbr="+$("#nbr").val()+"&page="+page+"&cols="+cols+"&tab="+tabs+"&where="+where,
                            url: "../../RestaurantCommande/ajaxLoadArticles"
                        }).responseText;
        $("#cmds").html(ret);
    }
$(document).ready(function() {        
        loadData(1);
        ...
}
</script>
```

In the `$(document).ready` I want to hide the elements having a class `qtecmd`. How to do that ?

Comment: Please post your js code. Do you want hide the elements after the ajax call is ended?

Comment: After you insert the html in your div, you can access it from DOM, like this: $('.qtecmd').hide(). is it what you want?

Comment: @pabgaran yes I want to hide them after the ajax call is ended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this after the insertion like this :

```
$("#cmds").html(ret).find('.qtecmd').hide();
```

If you want to do it directly in the `$(document).ready`, you can do this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {        
    loadData(1);
    $('#cmds').find('.qtecmd').hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create 2 class called active and inactive and then through jquery once you want to show it you can again remove inactive and add active

```js
$("#cmds .qtcmds").addClass("inactive");
    $("#cmds .qtcmds").removeClass("inactive").addClass("active");
```

```css
    #cmds .gtecmd.active { display: block;}
    #cmds .gtecmd.inactive { display: none;}
```

Comment: I want to hide them dynamically but not statically ; I want to show them when I click the tiles !

Comment: then i think you can create 2 different class like .active { display: block;} and .inactive { display: none;} and through javascript you can add/remove the required class